# How to find the side of the square ,by using trigonometry

Tags: trigonometry, solution-verification, radicals, pythagorean-triples

There is a square with diagonal length of 'a", the question is to find the length of the sides. it can be found by Pythagorean theorem. but I tried to do it with trigonometry, considering the properties of a square but it doesn't resemble the first answer, so I was wondering what did I forget/mistake?

Comment: Well, in order to pinpoint the mistake - can you write down the full question statement, the **proper** solution and your attempt?

Comment: What did you use in trigonometry?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**:

A side is an orthogonal projection of the diagonal, onto a line making  an angle of $\pi/4$ with the diagonal.

Comment: Yes, it is 45 degree i used it and the diagonal as hypotenuse, then with sine formula it becomes, radical 2 over 2  times a" but in the Pythagoras it becomes a"divided by radical 2..

Comment: Well, $\sqrt2/2$ is the same as $1/\sqrt 2$.

Comment: @MeskeremMitiku Do you know about rationalising the denominator? If not, then I'll update my answer.

Comment: Reilly , how? It is not by rationalizaton right?

Comment: You can do it by rationalisation in a direction, but more simply, in the other direction, you just simplify $\sqrt2/2=\sqrt2/(\sqrt2)^2$.

Comment: Tank you so much @ Bernard

Answer (score 1):

Let the side length of the square equal $b$, and the hypotenuse $a$. By Pythagoras' Theorem, we have

\begin{align}
b^2+b^2&=a^2 \\
2b^2&=a^2 \\
b^2&=\frac{a^2}{2}\\
b&=\sqrt{\frac{a^2}{2}}=\frac{\sqrt{a^2}}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{a}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}a
\end{align}

Alternatively, the angle between $a$ and $b$ is $45$ degrees. We know this because a square has $4$ right angles, which are bisected (cut in half) by the diagonal. Therefore,

\begin{align}
\sin(45)&=\frac{b}{a}\\
\end{align}

Now find the value of $\sin(45)$, and rearrange the equation to find $b$. Hopefully this answer is familiar.

It seems that part of your confusion stems from the fact that you are unsure about rationalising the denominator:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
$$

Consider the left-hand side of the above equality. Multiplying $\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}$ by $1$ does not change its value:

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\times1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}
$$

We also know that

$$
1=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}
$$

Therefore,

$$
\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\times1=\frac{1}{\sqrt 2}\times\frac{\sqrt{2}}{\sqrt{2}}=\frac{\sqrt 2}{2}
$$

Comment: You are right ,but if the side is b"(one side) then on the calculation u do, it says, 2b=a×radical 2,but this will disproof the kind of low" that says,if a side of the square is b" then, the diagonal is =b×radical 2,rearranging the equation it becomes radical 2 divided by b" w/c is not the same,

Comment: @MeskeremMitiku I'm sorry but I don't understand what you are saying. Could you please clarify?

Comment: I think i  did, but i used it the wrong way, thank you so much @joe

Comment: @MeskeremMitiku No worries! Let me know if you have any questions.

Comment: Tank you, i will

Answer (score 0):

The diagonal makes a $45^\circ=\frac{\pi}{4}$ angle with all vertices it touches with its endpoints.

If you look at trig identities [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20trigonometric%20identities%20are,of%20one%20or%20more%20angles.),  you will see that $\sin\frac{\pi}{4}=\cos\frac{\pi}{4}=\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}\approx 0.707$ no matter which corner or which side of the diagonal you chose. The length of each side is $\frac{\sqrt{2}a}{2}$.